# how to decode something that is encoded with encodeUri()

Tags: php, javascript

If you encode something using javascript's `encodeURI()` method, how do yo get the decoded string in PHP?

I have string `name= "salman mahmood"` which I'm sending via POST message to my server. When I `alert()` the string at client side it gives me "salman%20mahmood" after encoding. 
At server side I'm decoding it using `urldecode()` but the result I'm getting is "salman". Do I need a different method to decode? the `rawurldecode` isnt working either; I just need the value with the space restored back.

Edit: thanks every one for the suggestions but im writing the code as follows and it still doesnt work!!

```
<input type="text" id="chapterNumber" value=<?php echo rawurldecode("chapter%20Two"); ?> disabled="disabled">
```

it only prints "chapter"

Comment: You don't need to decode it manually in php since php does that automatically. If you still have `%20` in the data - then it seems like you encoded the source string twice. Check out what data has actually been passed from the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it into quotes ' '

```
<input type="text" id="chapterNumber" value='<?php echo rawurldecode("chapter%20Two"); ?>'disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: thanksss genesis...it solved the prblm. i also read somewhere that php automatically decodes the url..but in my case it isnt decoding it...i hav to use rawurldecode. thanks again

Comment: @Salmanmahmood: it decodes in case that string comes from ajax/url request